# Strange database insertion issue in Phonegap and SQLite

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I have following Phonegap SQLlite insertion statement:

```
tx.executeSql('insert into "'+gAppConfig.configTable+'" (key , value) values("uniqueId","'+uniqueId+'")' , [] , querySuccess, errorQuery);
```

Both the columns are text data-type, but the insert query is not working.

uniqueId is a random 8 character string like 'e72361c6'. Strange thing is when I directly insert "e7231c6", it works. Why is it not working with variable? One more thing to note here is that the random string has been generated by decrypting the value stored in server-database. I am decrypting and getting the 8-bit random string on the server and decrypted value is then sent to the device, stored in a variable and inserted in the database which is where the problem occurs.

When I alert the string just before insertion, it shows correct 8 character string. On the other hand, if I don't decrypt and simply send the 8 character string from the server, insertion happens successfully. Maybe it has something to do with encode/decode string format.

Comment: Does sqlite distinguish between single and double quotes?

Comment: i have tried with both single and double quotes

Comment: try removing the xtra " u have.  Like this ... tx.executeSql('insert into '+gAppConfig.configTable+' (key , value) values("uniqueId","'+uniqueId+'")' , [] , querySuccess, errorQuery);

Comment: and btw, what happens if you use a variable, does it create an error or what happens? :)

Comment: yes it throws and sqlite error 'Undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Just replace of "uniqueId" with NULL

```
tx.executeSql('insert into "'+gAppConfig.configTable+'" (key , value) values(null,"'+uniqueId+'")' , [] , querySuccess, errorQuery);
```

Or you can use this

```
tx.executeSql('insert into "'+gAppConfig.configTable+'" (value) values("'+uniqueId+'")' , [] , querySuccess, errorQuery);
```

remember that you are dealing with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) and not with the normal SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, identifiers like table/column names should use double quotes, while strings should use single quotes. (Other quotes are supported for compatibility with other DBs, but might be misinterpreted.)

```
INSERT INTO "MyTable"("col1", "col2")
VALUES ('ABC', 'xyz')
```